# Eclipse Galileo click problem on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: eclipse, click, ubuntu-9.10, galileo

I've just upgrade my Ubuntu from 9.04 to 9.10 and I'm experimenting a very annoying problem with Eclipse Galileo.

The problem is that Eclipse doesn't catch some button clicks. For example, I've tried to install a plugin and I clicked on next, and then nothing happened.

I didn't have the same problem before the upgrade of my Ubuntu version.

Comment: This might get more traction on superuser, who knows if it's eclipse-specific or  generic bit of Ubuntu-ism.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a [known bug (bug 291257)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291257) with Eclipse 3.5 and GTK+ 2.8 (fixed in Eclipse 3.6). The workaround is to set the  `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS` environment variable to `true` before to start Eclipse.

I use the following startup script for Eclipse:

```
#!/bin/sh
export MOZILLA_FIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/mozilla/
export ECLIPSE_HOME=/opt/IBM/eclipse
export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true # workaround for Karmic - http://bit.ly/T8MIc
$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

The important part is the line `export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true`.

Comment: That's what I do for the same problem, and it works great! If you're ever stuck in Eclipse without that, though: Usually you can still work the button by TABbing to it and typing -space- on the keyboard.

Comment: I think, the script is not a solution. If eclipse would restart, a instance still has the same problem.

Comment: @Nyambayar feel free to not use it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change in GTK with Karmic.  Here are the relevant bugs:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swt-gtk/+bug/463086

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291257

Comment: And the workaround in the first answer will work to fix this (according to the bug reports)