# Java perspective is not visible in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.5

I installed eclipse on a new unubtu install, via the package manager. I have Galileo. I copied my home directory from an older machine, and tried to open that workspace. Now I dont see any java perspective.

(Possibly, all the info above is not relevant, but I just wanted to add any possible info, as this a clean install of Eclipse via package manager, so I cant think of any other non standard thing I might have done.)

Comment: even in windows>open perspective>other ?

Comment: You probably already checked, but just in case: If you choose "Window -> Open perspective -> Other ...", do you see any option for "Java" in that list?

Comment: No, dont see Java there. Without other, nothing is visible. Inside other I see, Debug, Resource(Default) and Team syncronysing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens if you go to *Window > Open Perspective > Other...*? Don't you see *Java* listed there?

If not, I don't think the problem is related to the workspace from your previous configuration. But maybe you did copy a `~/.eclipse` directory from your old machine and this one may cause problems. Try to rename it as `~/.eclipse.save` for example and restart Eclipse to see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, I renamed eclipse dir, and I can see the Java perspective now. I still dont have any of the create new class or other options etc in File->New or Toolbar. This is what my window looks like, http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/34188/screenshot_004_9OLrxw.png

Comment: Ok. Small step forward. But the name of the Java perspective sill looks strange (I don't have any `<>` surrounding it). And I have no particular problems with *File > New*. I don't know what the problem is here. Maybe reinstall the package (purging it completely). Or forget the package and install it manually (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE#User%20installation). I have no problem with a manually installed version. Oh, and don't forget the GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS trick (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816485/eclipse-galileo-click-problem-on-ubuntu-9-10/1816499#1816499).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean you already checked in the usual places for perspectives, or if Java Perspective didn't show up by default...

Java perspective should be available under the "Open Perspective" icon in the top right, or by going to Window -> Open Perspective -> Java.

I don't use the Ubuntu-packaged Eclipse, though...

Comment: Jeff, dont see it there. Also added comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a Java perspective even in "Other", you have downloaded one of the Eclipse versions intended for something else than Java.   Do it again, but be certain to get the Java or the Java EE version.

Note that Eclipse *IS* available in the Ubuntu software repository, but it is the version which was current when that version of Ubuntu came out.  For the 9.04 I use it is Eclipse 3.4 and I need 3.5, hence I downloaded it myself.

Answer (score -8):

Yes, without perspective you will never be able to see an Eclipse from the viewpoint of Galileo.

- The sun's radius (695,500 km) and its distance (149,000,000 km)
- The moon's radius (1,737.4 km) and its distance (384,403 km)

You will need to do a "perspective divide". So the perspective radii are:

- Sun: 0.00467
- Moon: 0.00452

Thanks to this divide, the moon is almost big enough to block out the entire sun.

So, yes, Perspective is needed to show the Eclipse.

Comment: Actualy I just want to see an image of eclipse, so perspective is not exactly necseaary. But obviously, perspective, esp. someone elses, always helps.