# Marker Bar is not visible in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for JAVA development. But Marker bar in text editor is not visible so I can not able to put debug point(Breakpoints) in my Code.

Kindly suggest how to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

The only case where I saw this ([maker bar](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-66.htm) not visible) is:

- the Java perspective isn't selected (see "[Java perspective is not visible in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897223/java-perspective-is-not-visible-in-eclipse?rq=1)")
- the Java file isn't part of the sources
- the Java file is the result of a .class/jar decompilation ("[Java Decompiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375037/java-decompiler)").

Check if you aren't in one of this cases.